# Natural sort an array of rows based on values in one column

Tags: php, sorting, multidimensional-array, natural-sort

I have this multidimensional array:

```
$data[] = array('name' => 'Mini 16', 'id' => 105);
$data[] = array('name' => 'Mini 15', 'id' => 5650);
$data[] = array('name' => 'Mini 100', 'id' => 9889);
$data[] = array('name' => 'Mini 20', 'id' => 587);
```

I want to order the array by `name` column sorting naturally, but is difficult for me.

The expected result:

```
[
    ['name' => 'Mini 15', 'id' => 5650],
    ['name' => 'Mini 16', 'id' => 105],
    ['name' => 'Mini 20', 'id' => 587],
    ['name' => 'Mini 100', 'id' => 9889]
]
```

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11267990/how-to-understand-usort-logic and this two links: http://pastebin.com/5J4VAM7S http://pastebin.com/YUcT92CV

Comment: Please also check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7839198/array-multisort-with-natural-sort

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`usort()`](http://php.net/usort) to sort the array by a custom function, and use [`strnatcmp()`](http://php.net/strnatcmp) to do the natural comparison of two strings like so:

```
usort( $data, function( $el1, $el2) { return strnatcmp( $el1['name'], $el2['name']); });
```

So before, your array was this:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(7) "Mini 16"
    ["id"]=>
    int(105)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(7) "Mini 15"
    ["id"]=>
    int(5650)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(8) "Mini 100"
    ["id"]=>
    int(9889)
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(7) "Mini 20"
    ["id"]=>
    int(587)
  }
}
```

And [now it looks like](http://viper-7.com/KTp0lg):

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(7) "Mini 15"
    ["id"]=>
    int(5650)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(7) "Mini 16"
    ["id"]=>
    int(105)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(7) "Mini 20"
    ["id"]=>
    int(587)
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(8) "Mini 100"
    ["id"]=>
    int(9889)
  }
}
```

Note that for lower versions of PHP, you won't be able to use an anonymous function, and would instead need something like this:

```
usort( $data, create_function( '$el1, $el2', 'return strnatcmp( $el1[\'name\'], $el2[\'name\']);' ));
```

Comment: @user1499315 - You're quite welcome! If my post answered your question, please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Also, welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 3):

If you're using PHP 5.4 or newer, you can use `array_multisort` with the `SORT_NATURAL` flag. Just follow Example #3 in the http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php documentation, but add the `SORT_NATURAL` option.

Answer (score 0):

As half-answered by Craig, `array_multisort()` will be more performant than `usort()` because `array_multisort()` doesn't make iterated function calls.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/uQEgO))

```
array_multisort(array_column($data, 'name'), SORT_NATURAL, $data);
var_export($data);
```

---

This is the modern, arrow-function syntax for nickb's answer.

Code (PHP7.4 and higher): ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/YtedF))

```
usort($data, fn($a, $b) => strnatcmp($a['name'], $b['name']));
var_export($data);
```