# Naturally sort associative rows in a 2d array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, associative-array, natural-sort

How to sort for humans (natural sort) an associative array in php?

Following code:

```
$notSorted = array( 
    array('Title' => 'rose', 'Price' => 1.25, 'Number' => '10'),
    array('Title' => 'daisy', 'Price' => 0.75, 'Number' => '1'),
    array('Title' => 'orchid', 'Price' => 1.15, 'Number' => '7')
);
```

I bet that sorting is going to occur here:

```
foreach ( $notSorted as $val )
    echo $val['Number'], " - ";
```

Is going to output:

```
10 - 
1 - 
7 -
```

And how to get 'Number' sorted (for humans)? Like:

```
1 - 
7 - 
10 -
```

Also what if 'Number' is an int, and what if it's a string?

Answer (score 1):

You can try it by this way:

```
<?php

function record_sort($records, $field, $reverse=false)
 {
     $hash = array();

    foreach($records as $record)
     {
         $hash[$record[$field]] = $record;
     }

    ($reverse)? krsort($hash) : ksort($hash);

    $records = array();

    foreach($hash as $record)
     {
         $records []= $record;
     }

    return $records;
 }

// Example below

$airports = array
 (
     array( "code" => "LHR", "name" => "Heathrow" ),
     array( "code" => "LGW", "name" => "Gatwick" ),
 );

printf("Before: <pre>%s</pre>", print_r($airports, true));

$airports = record_sort($airports, "name");

printf("After: <pre>%s</pre>", print_r($airports, true));

?>

Example Outputs:

Before: Array
 (
     [0] => Array ( [code] => LHR, [name] => Heathrow )
     [1] => Array ( [code] => LGW, [name] => Gatwick )
 )

After: Array
 (
     [0] => Array ( [code] => LGW, [name] => Gatwick )
     [1] => Array ( [code] => LHR, [name] => Heathrow )
 )
```

From http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php

Comment: this solution will drop records with duplicate keys. append a counter to the hash key (`$hash[$record[$field].$count] = $record; $count++;`) and it will work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

The field "Number" is string, so it is being compared char by char not thousands by thousands, then hundreds by hundreds and so on.

You can write your own sorting function and use it with `usort` or using `sort` with `SORT_NUMERIC`, maybe `array_multi_sort`.

Answer (score 0):

If the `Number` field is an integer (or float), you can just use `array_multisort` and specify that you want to sort on the `Number` field. Example #3 in the http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php documentation shows you how to do this for an associative array.

Things are more difficult if `Number` is a string -- you'll have to do a "natural" sort in that case, to ensure that "7" comes before "10". If you're using PHP 5.4 or newer, you can use `array_multisort` with the `SORT_NATURAL` flag. 
If you're using something older than PHP 5.4, you'll probably have to use `usort` and `strnatcmp`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/11315019/26311 for details on how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the 3-way comparison operator in your `usort()` call, numeric strings will be automatically compared as numeric values.  You don't need to make an special declaration or declare an explicit flag.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/KQKnO))

```
$array = [
    ['Title' => 'rose', 'Price' => 1.25, 'Number' => '10'],
    ['Title' => 'daisy', 'Price' => 0.75, 'Number' => '1'],
    ['Title' => 'orchid', 'Price' => 1.15, 'Number' => '7']
];

usort($array, fn($a, $b) => $a['Number'] <=> $b['Number']);
var_export($array);
```

Output:

```
array (
  1 => 
  array (
    'Title' => 'daisy',
    'Price' => 0.75,
    'Number' => '1',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'Title' => 'orchid',
    'Price' => 1.15,
    'Number' => '7',
  ),
  0 => 
  array (
    'Title' => 'rose',
    'Price' => 1.25,
    'Number' => '10',
  ),
)
```

The `array_multisort()` version of the same behavior is: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/scgmd))

```
array_multisort(array_column($array, 'Number'), SORT_NUMERIC, $array);
```