# How to sort associative array based on key in php

Tags: php, sorting, multidimensional-array

I am building a nested menu with custom sorting function. I am stuck in sorting the sub menu items of each menu.
How can i sort the sub menu items of About, Services, etc of user defined order?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Array
(
    [About] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => About us
                    [1] => about.php
                )
            [5] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Who we are
                    [1] => who-we-are.php
                )

        )

    [Services] => Array
        (
            [5] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Web Design
                    [1] => web-design.php
                )

            [10] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Web development
                    [1] => web-development.php
                )

            [15] => Array
                (
                    [0] => SEO
                    [1] => seo.php
                )

        )
)
```

Comment: Take a look on [array multisort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php). If you still can not find a solution. I can provide an example.

Comment: What do you mean with "user defined order"? The user should be able to put the menus and submenus in whatever order they want? (E.g. put Services before About? And then put for example the different submenus in Services in the order "Web development", "SEO" and "Web Design"?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. I've already tried usort, array multisort, etc but i am not succeed on that. And example would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Lenny Yes, you're right. i am using jQuery ui sortable for that function.

Answer (score 0):

We are going to sort each submenu array (eg about us, services) separately. But if we add an outer loop we can sort them at once

```
foreach ($subMenuArray as $key => $row) 
{
    $innerArray = $row;        // This is the array that holds the menu items 
    $value = $row[0];          // That is the word About us, Who we are
    // Here we build an array that holds the actual values we want to sort.
    $sortingReference[$key] = $value;
}

// Using array_multisort we are sorting our main array 
// referencing to the array we built above
// Sort the subMenuArray with menu items descending
array_multisort($sortingReference, SORT_DESC, $subMenuArray);
```

Comment: it is possible to sort in user defined custom order? i.e. not ascending or descending

Comment: @devdarsh Have a look at usort.

Comment: @devdarsh It is not possible to mix those two (multisot and usort). You have to implement a function that follows `multisort` logic but using `usort` as sorting function instead. You can use an insight from here : [Use array_multisort() with custom function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11120986/use-array-multisort-with-custom-function) and here : [array_multisort with natural sort](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7839198/array-multisort-with-natural-sort)